# jquery ScrollTop animation percent not pixels

Tags: jquery, fade

I would first like to say that I am new to jQuery. I am using this script to animate the background color of two divs when the user scrolls to that point. the first div works fine, but #contact doesn't work because #contact is positioned 500% from the top, so the animation fires when I scroll down 500 pixels. I do not know how to change it from pixels to percent.

I am using this with just the color section of java UI and the latest version of jQuery.

Also, I know this is another question but is there a way once you scroll past the div for it to go back to its original state so that if the user scrolls back up, the animate will fire again?

**JS FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/8SWG4/

> $(window).scroll(function() {
>
> ```
> if($(window).scrollTop() > 500){
> $("#contact").stop().animate({
>       backgroundColor:  '#fff',
>     }, 1000);
> }
>  else{
>
> $("#about").stop().animate({
>       backgroundColor:  '#000',
>     }, 1000);     
>  }
>
> });
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(element).offset().top` to detect the scroll passes to that element.

Sample DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/8SWG4/6/

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= $("#blog").offset().top){
        $("#contact").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor:  '#000',
        }, 2000);
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() <= $("#blog").offset().top){
        $("#contact").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor:  '#fff',
        }, 2000);
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= $("#home").offset().top/2){
        $("#about").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor:  '#000',
        }, 2000);     
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() <= $("#home").offset().top/2){
        $("#about").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor:  '#fff',
        }, 2000);     
    }
});
```

Comment: is there a way to fade the background, not set an alert? i am trying to use the code from #about section but it doesn't seem to be working. would it be possible to edit your answer so the #about works the same as the contact, but i want to have them fade to different colors. thank you so much

Comment: thanks you! finally, it works. is there a way to set the animation when #contact comes into the viewport, not when the top of the div hits the top of the page? i say this because it is the div right at the bottom of the page

Comment: check my update answer and demo, simple change $("#contact").offset().top to $("#blog").offset().top

Comment: if it works for you, you may accept the answer and upvote too.

Comment: works perfect, thank you so much. i would upvote your answer but i do not have enough reputation, i am sorry

Comment: sorry to bother you, but i have another two questions. i am trying to figure it out on my own but failing haha.
1. is there a way to set them back to the original state after scrolling so if the user scrolls back, they see the animation again?

Comment: and 2. is there a way to put a delay on? i tried    $("#div").stop().delay(500).animate({ and didn't work. i can not thank you enough for your help!

Comment: your question 1 and 2 fixed, Check my update answer and demo again, you can change 1000 to any delay you want in...$("#contact").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor:  '#000',
        }, 2000);

Comment: i have marked your answer as correct. but this delay doesn't seem to do anything, i can't see the delay anwyhere. and the jsfiddle delay doesn't seem to work

Comment: the original state is working, thanks. but i'm also trying to make the fade start after a 1 second delay or maybe 300 pixels from the top of the screen rather then the top if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

500% is out of the screen, will not work. You mean 50% or? how do you pass height to your divs?

Anyway, you cannot fire the scroll height directly on % but you can do like:

```
var a = $(document).height();
var a3= Math.floor(a * 0.3);  // 30% 
var a5= Math.floor(a * 0.5);  // 50%
var a8= Math.floor(a * 0.8);  // 80%
```

I used `$(document).height();`, but if you have an wrapper div you can use that also, like `$('#div_id').height();`

To have the animations "re-start" when user scrolls back check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKFXk/). You can also do yeyene's suggestion to use `$(element).offset().top`.

I adapted the code from your other question to:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    a = b = c = false;
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() < 400) {
        a = true;
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 399 && $(window).scrollTop() < 900) {
        b = true;
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 899 ) {
        c = true;
    }
    $("#home").stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: a ? '#00f' : '#fff',
    }, 1000);
    $("#about").stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: b ? '#0f0' : '#fff',
    }, 1000);
    $("#contact").stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: c ? '#f00' : '#fff',
    }, 1000);
});
```